# Upgrage 13.10 to 14.04 is stucked in Debconf

Tags: upgrade

I am upgrading ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 LTS.

During upgrade a popup come and message is `"what do you want to do about configuration file php.ini? "`
then I select "start a new shell to examine the situation". press "forward" button.

After that upgrade process look like stoped.

If I write command in terminal "sudo apt-get update" it returns

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```